# Introduce a counter into a loop within scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm writing a small program which will convert a very large file into multiple smaller files, each file will contain 100 lines.

I'm iterating over a lines iteration :

```
  while (lines.hasNext) {
      val line = lines.next()
  }
```

I want to introduce a counter and when it reaches a certain value, reset the counter and proceed. In java I would do something like :

```
int counter = 0;
      while (lines.hasNext) {
          val line = lines.next()
if(counter == 100){
 counter = 0;
}
++counter
      }
```

Is there something similar in scala or an alternative method ?

Comment: What are you using the counter for?

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral The counter is used to control amount of lines to write

Answer (score 9, accepted):

traditionally in scala you use `.zipWithIndex`

```
scala> List("foo","bar")
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar)

scala> for((x,i) <- res0.zipWithIndex) println(i + " : " +x)
0 : foo
1 : bar
```

(this will work with your lines too, as far as they are in Iterator, e.g. has `hasNext` and `next()` methods, or some other scala collection)

But if you need a complicated logic, like resetting counter, you may write it the same way as in java:

```
var counter = 0
while (lines.hasNext) {
  val line = lines.next()
  if(counter % 100 == 0) {
    // now write to another file
  }
}
```

Maybe you can tell us why you want to reset counter, so we may say how to do it better?

**EDIT** 
according to your update, that is better to do using grouped method, as @pr1001 proposed:

```
lines.grouped(100).foreach(l => l.foreach(/* write line to file*/))
```

Comment: ive updated my question to provide more detail. your solution seems good to me....

Comment: lines.grouped(100).foreach(l => l.foreach(/* write line to file*/)) throws an error : not enough arguments for method foreach: (f: String => U)Unit. Unspecified value parameter f.

Comment: @user470184 cause you need to write code instead of comments in inner foreach (for debug you can replace it with `println`)

Answer (score 3):

If your resetting counter represents the fact that there are repeated groups of data in the original list, you might want to use the `grouped` method:

```
scala> val l = List("one", "two", "three", "four")
l: List[java.lang.String] = List(one, two, three, four)

scala> l.grouped(2).toList
res0: List[List[java.lang.String]] = List(List(one, two), List(three, four))
```

**Update:** Since you're reading from a file, you should be able to pretty efficiently iterate over the file:

```
val bigFile = io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/verybigfile")
val groupedLines = bigFile.getLines.grouped(2).zipWithIndex
groupedLines.foreach(group => {
  val (lines, index) = group
  val p = new java.io.PrintWriter("/tmp/" + index)
  lines.foreach(p.println)
  p.close()
})
```

Of course this could also be written as a for comprehension...

You might even be able to get better performance by converting `groupedLines` to a parallel collection with `.par` before writing out each group of lines to its own file.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO (though I'd go for the for-expression and squeeze lines 2, 3, and 4 into one). Generally not a good idea to do I/O with parallel collections since it's much faster for a hard disk to sequentially write files rather than jump around trying to write 1000 at once.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
lines grouped 100 flatMap (_.zipWithIndex) foreach {
  case (line, count) => //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `zipWithIndex` along with some transformation.

```
scala> List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).zipWithIndex.map(p => (p._1, p._2 % 3))
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,0), (20,1), (30,2), (40,0), (50,1))
```